# Changing an Android Service's started state from START_STICKY to START_NON_STICKY

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a service working well in a running process. It controls a specific broadcast receiver even when the main activity isn't shown. It also starts up at a certain interval on its own to check some parameters. On detection that no broadcast receivers exist, I can stop the service outright until one is registered or it restarts itself at the interval. In the meantime, the service will be running in START_NOT_STICKY mode.

However, when I do connect to the service and register a receiver, is there a way to change its running state from START_NOT_STICKY to START_STICKY from within it? Or will I simply have to use a isRegistered flag in the receiver, stop and restart the service and check its value within onStartCommand? Is this a good pattern to use or are there any better?

The main reason for doing this is so to not have a process running in the background when it isn't required by the app.

Answer (score 0):

From android dev website [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), START_STICKY means the service will hang around after it is done running its commands, START_NOT_STICKY will end after running its commands.
From your description you keep saying you are running services and adding a broadcast receiver to it?  Broadcast receivers are actually used to receive external requests regardless of any other services.  The broadcast receiver will actually be the first point of contact for the app to receive external requests, then it would be responsible for starting a service to run any needed commands. As far as your services you need for running commands periodically those should just be started and ended as needed based off of the above defenition of service flags.

Example flow for GCM (Google cloud messaging).

1. Cloud server send a message to a registered device.
2. Going through the google play services on the registered the device, an intent is sent to the Broadcast receiver for the registered app.
3. Broad-cast receiver receives intent, hands it off to a service which performs any further commands necessary for processing (I.E. showing notifications etc..).

Comment: I already had it working like that. The difference is I have moved my receiver into the service, as it is setup to receiver broadcasts that are protected by the system. This means you have to actually register to receive them in code. If I stop my service, then the receiver stops as well. If you place a broadcast receiver in the manifest, this is then run in a separate process automatically by the system, if your app happens to be destroyed.

Comment: But just a comment, this is not an answer to my question. I am asking if it is possible to change a Service's state from START_STICKY to START_NOT_STICKY within itself. This doesn't answer it.